# Managing different objects in an heterogeneous Java array

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, containers, heterogeneous

I have to solve this "container problem" in Java. I have an array made up with different figures and I'd like the following code to work:

```
 package container;
    class Figure{
        public void draw() {}
        public String getColor() { return null; }
    }

    class Square extends Figure{
        @Override
        public void draw(){
            System.out.println("Square");
        }
    }

    class Circle extends Figure{
        @Override
        public void draw(){
            System.out.println("Circle");
        }
        public float getRadius(){
            return 8;
        }
    }

    public class Container {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Figure[] figures = new Figure[3];
            figures[0]= new Circle();
            figures[1]= new Circle();
            figures[2]= new Square();

            for(Figure figure:figures){
                figure.getColor();
                figure.draw(); 
                ((Circle) figure).getRadius();          
            }        
    }
}
```

Where you can see there is a problem because `Square` hasn't got a `getRadius()` method. I have the following restrictions:

- can't use generics
- can't use `instanceof`

It should be a nice object-oriented design solution.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Square is not a circle - how it's that line supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add an `enum FigureType` to your base class that identifies the child class?

```
public static enum FigureType {

    Square,
    Circle
}

public static class Figure {
    private FigureType type;

    public Figure(FigureType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public FigureType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void draw() {
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You would have to add a default constructor to each child class that calls the parent class constructor with its `FigureType`.

```
public static class Square extends Figure {

    public Square() {
        super(FigureType.Square);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Square");
    }
}

public static class Circle extends Figure {

    public Circle() {
        super(FigureType.Circle);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Circle");
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return 8;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Figure[] figures = new Figure[3];
    figures[0] = new Circle();
    figures[1] = new Circle();
    figures[2] = new Square();

    for (Figure figure : figures) {
        figure.getColor();
        figure.draw();
        if (figure.getType() == FigureType.Circle) {
            ((Circle) figure).getRadius();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Circle
Circle
Square
```

No exception

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `getRadius` to Figure, and then throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` in the implementation of square?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the `instanceof` you can declare abstract method in the `Figure` class and add dummy implementation for figures that doesn't need it. The following code without `instanceof` and java generics works:

```
package container;

abstract class Figure {
    public void draw(){};
    public String getColor(){return null;};

    protected abstract float getRadius();
}

class Square extends Figure{
    @Override
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Square");
    }

    // zero radius for non-circle figures, for instance
    // or you can throw UnsupportedOperationException here.
    public float getRadius() { return 0;} 
}

class Circle extends Figure{
    @Override
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Circle");
    }
    public float getRadius(){
        return 8;
    }
}

public class Container {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Figure[] figures = new Figure[3];
        figures[0]= new Circle();
        figures[1]= new Circle();
        figures[2]= new Square();

        for(Figure figure:figures){
            figure.getColor();
            figure.draw(); 

            figure.getRadius();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that would perfect but I was given the restriction "can't use instanceof"

Answer (score 0):

You want to write code that works for all types of `Figures` and you want different behavior if the `Figure` is a `Circle` or `Square`. This is why they invented polymorphism. Your code looks like:

```
Figure f;
if (f is Circle) {
  doFoo();
} else {
  doBar();
}
```

Instead the better way to do this is as follows:

```
interface Figure {
  public void do();
}

class Circle implements Figure {
  public void do() {
    doFoo();
  }
}

class Square implements Figure {
  public void do() {
    doBar();
  }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
Figure f;
f.do();
```

Comment: it's right but what if circle has got some behaviour (getRadious) that it's not present in square and figure?

Comment: Then don't expose it to the user. Why does the user need the radius.

Comment: The user is probably trying to perform some operation related to `Figures` and this operation I call `do`.